# Folks can't reply to my e-mail

Tags: email

When people reply to an e-mail I send them it automatically goes to this address:  `mrbendavid99@gmail.com`.

I know this is some kind of scam address, but I don't know what to do about it. Please help.

Comment: Your e-mail account has been compromised. Go in, change the password to something more secure, and then change the "reply-to" address back to yours (or blank it out completely). What e-mail system are you using?

Comment: What email client are you using?

Comment: To expand on JNK's comment: are you using webmail? Some email program like Outlook or Thunderbird? Be as specific as you can.  If possible, edit your question to include the full headers of one of your email, which you can probably see by sending email to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Check / set your reply-to address in your email client.